# Python Scapy import/load and inspect packet

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm trying to load and inspect packet in Scapy. The packet comes from Wireshark as a copy of 'escaped string' so it looks as shown below:

```
"\x6c\x0b\x84\x42\x41\xbf\x00\x09\x0f\x09\x00\x06\x08\x00\x45\xb8\x00\x4c\x0b\xe6\x40\x00\x37\x11\x1d\x17\x2e\xaf\xe0\x07\x0a\x39\x00\xfd\x00\x7b\x00\x7b\x00\x38\xc2\xa9\x1c\x03\x0a\xea\x00\x00\x08\x5b\x00\x00\x0c\xa9\xb2\xd7\xe4\x18\xe7\xe3\x91\x9d\x3d\xb0\x7b\xac\xe7\xe3\x99\x44\x08\x09\xbd\x18\xe7\xe3\x99\x44\x0a\x48\xbf\x72\xe7\xe3\x99\x44\x0a\x4a\xff\x91"
```

I know it is NTP packet but how can i load it to scapy and inspect if it is NTP but not veryfing src and dst ports ?
I was trying to import as a hexcap (scapy.import_hexcap) but it always shows output as below :

```
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = None
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = ip
  chksum    = None
  src       = 127.0.0.1
  dst       = 127.0.0.1
  \options   \

None
>>>
```

I know from Wireshark that source address suppose to be 46.175.224.7 and destination address should be 10.57.0.253 output is incorrect.

If you have any ideas how to properly import packet ( not from cap file ) please let me know.

Regards
AD